# How can I tell if an incoming call is from OpenVBX but still see the caller's Caller ID information?

Tags: twilio

I have a OpenVBX/Twilio setup where I use its dial applet to call particular people in my company. However, when viewing an incoming call on my phone, I have no way to know if the caller is calling via OpenVBX or not.

Is there a way to customize OpenVBX/Twilio so that when viewing the caller's Caller ID on my phone, I can see the Caller ID information and some indicator that the call came through Twilio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is configurable in OpenVBX itself, or if you'd have to change some of the Dial applet code, but you could just use the CallerID (number) of a Twilio number, instead of using the CallerId of the incoming call.

Comment: In the Dial applet, I can specify whether the Caller ID is the Caller's Number (my current choice) or the VBX number. But if I specify the VBX number, then I don't know who's actually calling. Hence my question on whether I can get caller ID to tell me the Caller's Number with an indicator that it's coming via the VBX.

Comment: Note that the Dial applet has an "announce the caller" feature, but it just tells me that the call is for me. It doesn't reveal the source of the call.

Comment: For that you would have to modify the source of the dial plugin.

Comment: Do you know which source file contains the dial plugin source, and the right way to modify it? Specifically, can I just change the dial's callerId value to be an arbitrary string or is some format required?

Comment: You can only set a numeric ID (and one of your numbers). You could edit the 'whisper' (caller announce) feature to attempt to notify of the caller.

Comment: Can you clarify 'numeric ID' and 'one of your numbers'? By "one of your numbers", you mean the phone number of the caller or receiver? What would the numeric ID look like? Can you show me a small sample?

Comment: The only thing that can be used as a CallerId with Twilio is one of the numbers you've verified or purchased (or the incoming call's number). You can't set any string as CallerID.

Comment: I contacted Twilio support and confirmed that: "it is not possible to include an arbitrary string in the caller ID value, so there's no way to display 'V* [phone number.]' It *is* possible to select another validated phone number to use as the caller ID, but that number will be passed forward as a phone number to be formatted as the recipient device decides. Caller IDs are carefully controlled to avoid spoofing and fraud.". I'm going to mark your response as the answer since clearly, you can't see both values in caller id. Thanks.